# CTAD recursion problem for function wrappers with wrapper pointer as function argument

Tags: c++, ctad

I have a templated function wrapper with template type equal to return type of the function. Further the function's first argument is a pointer to the wrapper itself.

```cpp
template<typename R>
struct wrapper_t{
    using result_t = R;
    template<typename F, typename ...Ts>
    wrapper_t(F &&, Ts &&...){

    }
};
int foo(wrapper_t<int>*,double){
    return 2;
}
```

I'm trying to use user-defined deduction guides here in order to avoid specifying the template type such that I can use it like

```cpp
wrapper_t wrapper(foo,1.0);
```

But I don't know with what I should replace the question marks in the following guide with, because of the recursion.

```cpp
template<typename F, typename ...Ts>
wrapper_t(F &&, Ts &&...)->wrapper_t<std::invoke_result_t<F,/*???*/,Ts...>>;
```

Is ctad still doable here, if so how?

Comment: Well, I could easily write a `bar` that takes arbitrary `wrapper_t<T>` and returns `T`. What would be the correct deduction for `wrapper_t wrapper(bar);`? Basically, `F` defines a transformation on types, and you want to find a unique fixed point of that transformation. I suspect this is equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: I see, though the wrapper's type is the function's return type. So the function's return type must be known. By now I have come up with `template<typename F, typename ...Ts>wrapper_t(F &&f, Ts &&...args)->wrapper_t<decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(uintptr_t(),std::forward<Ts>(args)...))>;`. It works like a charm, still not 100% sure if such implicit casting of `uintptr_t` is of any trouble, but I think it is ok.

Comment: You are just passing `NULL`. I suspect `nullptr_t` would work just as well. `uintptr_t()` is a fancy way to write a null pointer constant. Note though that this will stop working as soon as `F` is overloaded, or is a template, or otherwise accepting more than one possible `wrapper_t` specialization.

Comment: @ezegoing, what is your use case where the function needs the wrapper to be invoked? Since the invocation has the function and the arguments, which are also the constructor arguments to the wrapper, it seems redundant.

Comment: @JeffGarrett I can think of many, this is the one I stumbled upon https://probablydance.com/2012/11/18/implementing-coroutines-with-ucontext/.